# How to explain the DIFFERENCE FUNCTION issues in MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, soundex

The [difference function in mssql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188753.aspx) is defined as :

> Returns an integer value that indicates the difference between the SOUNDEX values of two character expressions.

But testing with very short words or words that contains numbers produce... Strange results. And I haven't found any ressources that could explain the differences.

Examples :

```
select difference('C',''), difference('','C')                       --0,3
select difference('CC',''), difference('','CC')                     --0,2
select difference('1',''), difference('','1')                       --4,4
select difference('1C','C'), difference('C','1C')                   --3,0
select difference('1C','C'), difference('C','1C')                   --3,0
select difference('1CD','CD'), difference('CD','1CD')               --2,0
select difference('1CDCDC','CDCDC'), difference('CDCDC','1CDCDC')   --0,0
select difference('C1CDCD','CDCDC'), difference('CDCDC','C1CDCD')   --1,1
select difference('CD1CDC','CDCDC'), difference('CDCDC','CD1CDC')   --2,3
```

### The first case

```
Soundex('C') --> C000
Soundex('')  --> 0000

Difference('','C') --> 3, I have 3 '0'. Seems fine.
Difference('C','') --> 0, Why?
```

Any ressources?

Answer (score -2):

According to BOL, it is:

### Remarks

The integer returned is the number of characters in the SOUNDEX values that are the same. The return value ranges from 0 through 4: 0 indicates weak or no similarity, and 4 indicates strong similarity or the same values.

Comment: You only pasted a different `Difference` definition... This doesn't explain why `Difference('','C')` and `Difference('','C')` produce differents numbers.